# Getting "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')" Error while creating libraries

Tags: angular, user-interface, components, angular-library

I am creating library for card using components, creating 3 components.

1. card-body
2. card-header
3. card-footer
   when I try to build the library, it gives a error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')"

How do I fix this.

This is how the structure of the components look like
[image]

The Error I get is
[image]

Comment: can you share your ts code of the 3 components

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm encountering the exact same error building a library, and I have no clue where it is coming from.  I've literally commented out every single line in my app with "includes" in it to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

The build issue happening from beginning itself so it's possible missed something in @component decorator itself.

Like the mapping file extension missing (instead of scss mapped css)

Comment: This was exactly the solution for me.  I removed every file from my library (about 100), and started adding them back one-by-one because there were so many files and the error gave me no clue where to begin.  Luckily, I found it in the first ten components I added back.  I had a styleUrls: ['./my.component.css'], and I needed to change it to styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']

Comment: This was also the issue I had.

Needed to change the name of my style url from .css to .scss, to match the filename,

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error in Javascript: it means that a variable called `includes`, or an object with `includes` property, for example:

```
response {
  data: {
    includes: string;
  }
}
```

is trying to be read in your code, but either it is a declared variable which has not been initialized, or, more probably, it should be a key of an object which is not actually included in it (or maybe the object itself is undefined).

In our example, it means that `response.data` has not `includes` property, or even `response` has no `data` property at all.

If this variable comes out of an http request, this happens quite often due to distraction (for example, when one writes `response.includes` instead of `response.data.includes`). In that case, you'd better print the former variable with `console.log` to see what's wrong.

Comment: You're describing a run-time error.  The OP is describing a compile-time error.